# I cannot log in to the MySQL server

Tags: database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

When I tried to open phpMyadmin I've this problem: I wrote user name `root` and `null` password then I click GO. It tells me:

> Cannot log in to the MySQL server

I'm using WAMP server.

[image]

Comment: Create a username and password for phpmyadmin and then try to connect.

Comment: from config.inc.php ?